# Regex - Get x number of characters from a string but html tags does not count towards the count

Tags: javascript, regex

As the title suggests I need to get X amount of characters from a string but HTML is not including in the count.

Example string

```
Some <i>t</i>est <b>string</b> test
```

9 characters would output

```
Some <i>t</i>est
```

13 characters would output

```
Some <i>t</i>est <b>str
```

19 characters would output

```
Some <i>t</i>est <b>string</b> te
```

I'm not too sure where to go from the basic

```
(.*?){0,10}
```

Also, is there a way to make HTML encoded characters e.g. `&lt;` count as one character?

Comment: Try `^(?:(?:<[^<>]*>)*[^<]){9}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTenRJ/1).

Comment: That's great, although I have just thought a head, is there a way to make HTML encoded characters e.g. &lt; count as one character? also how do I upvote you on a comment?

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/aTenRJ/3)? `^(?:(?:<[^<>]*>|&lt;.*?&gt;)*.){9}`

Comment: Very close I've changed it a little to `^(?:(?:<[^<>]*>)|(?:&[^\s+]*;)*.){21}` but I want the &.*; to count as one letter. any ideas?

Comment: I've just worked it out `^(?:(?:&[^\s+]*;)|(?:<[^<>]*>)*.){21}` https://regex101.com/r/ecW1A4/1 change the number between 19 and 20 to see what I was aiming for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, I see. Please add these requirements to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a certain amount of chars from the string start excluding substrings like `<...>` from the count and counting `&XX*;` entities as one unit, you may use

```
^(?:&[^\s;]*;|(?:<[^<>]*>)*.){20}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hkwbHS/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group that will serve as a containter for the alternatives below:

  - `&[^\s;]*;` - a `&`, 0 or more chars other than whitespace and `;` and then `;`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:<[^<>]*>)*.` - 0 or more repetitions of `<`, 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>`, and then any char other than a line break char (use DOTALL modifier to match any char with `.`)
- `){20}` - end of the container group and the limiting quantifier tells the engine to match 20 consecutive occurrences of its pattern.